# rewrite taxonomy view results with parent/child when some terms have no parent

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to make a tree of taxonomy terms and keep the child-parent relationship.  So something like

```
-Parent1
--Child1
--child2
-Parent2
-Parent3
```

I couldn't find a way to do this with core, so I'm using the Views Tree module.  By following the instructions on the module page, I can output a hierarchical, bulleted, unordered list with proper indentation for the child terms.  However, I want to rewrite the fields as links like:

```
test/parent1
test/parent1/child1
test/parent1/child2
test/parent2
test/parent3
```

I'm using Fields:

```
 - Taxonomy term: Term ID
 - (Parent) Taxonomy term: Term ID
 - (Parent) Taxonomy term: Name
 - Taxonomy term: Name
```

only the last field is visible, and I have a relation "Taxonomy term: Parent term".  All this is per the instructions on the Views Tree page.  When I try and rewrite the field link using Fields->'taxonomy term: Name'->Rewrite Results->Output this field as a link->Link Path and use the replacement patterns in the form:

```
test/[name]/[name_1]
```

('name' references the term's parent name (if it exists); name_1 references the term name itself) it works fine for the child terms, since both parent and child are defined, I get:

```
test/<term's parent name>/<term name>
(e.g. test/Parent1/Child1)
```

However, the parent term links are rewritten as:

```
test//<term name>
(e.g. test//Parent1)
```

since the parent terms themselves have no parent.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?  I'm willing to scrap this module and try something else, but I couldn't get it working with core either.